# Svelte: How to use template expressions in a 'style' block?

Tags: typescript, tailwind-css, svelte, flowbite-svelte

I am trying to create a simple Svelte Component (NumberFormatting)

```
<script lang="ts">
    export let number: string ;

    const formatNumber = (value: string) => {
        return Number(value).toFixed(2);
        
    };

    const isNegative = (value: string): boolean => {
        return Number(value) < 0;
    };
</script>

<main>
    <p>{formatNumber(number)}</p>
</main>

<style>
    main {
        text-align: right;
    }

    p {
        margin: 0; /* Remove default margin to avoid extra space */
        color: {isNegative(number) ? 'red' : 'inherit'};
    }
</style>
```

And I got this error

```
11:11:08 PM [vite] Pre-transform error: Error while preprocessing /home/xxxxx/TestProjects/svelteDemo/src/NumberFormatting.svelte - [postcss] postcss-nested: /home/xxxxx/TestProjects/svelteDemo/src/NumberFormatting.svelte.vite-preprocess.css:8:3: Missed semicolon
11:11:10 PM [vite] Error when evaluating SSR module /src/routes/test/+page.svelte: failed to import "/src/NumberFormatting.svelte"
|- CssSyntaxError: /home/xxxxx/TestProjects/svelteDemo/src/NumberFormatting.svelte.vite-preprocess.css:8:3: Missed semicolon
...
{
  name: 'CssSyntaxError',
  id: '/home/xxxxx/TestProjects/svelteDemo/src/NumberFormatting.svelte',
  message: 'Error while preprocessing /home/xxxxx/TestProjects/svelteDemo/src/NumberFormatting2.svelte - [postcss] postcss-nested: /home/xxxxx/TestProjects/svelteDemo/src/NumberFormatting2.svelte.vite-preprocess.css:8:3: Missed semicolon',
  frame: '',
  code: '\n' +
    '\tmain {\n' +
    '\t\ttext-align: right;\n' +
    '\t}\n' +
    '\n' +
    '\tp {\n' +
    '\t\tmargin: 0; /* Remove default margin to avoid extra space */\n' +
    "\t\tcolor: {isNegative(2) ? 'red' : 'inherit'};\n" +
    '\t}\n',
  stack: 'CssSyntaxError: /home/xxxxx/TestProjects/svelteDemo/src/NumberFormatting.svelte.vite-preprocess.css:8:3: Missed semicolon\n' +
...
plugin: 'vite-plugin-svelte'
```

My postcss.config.cjs looks like this

```
const tailwindcss = require('tailwindcss');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const tailwindcssNesting = require('tailwindcss/nesting'); 
const postcssImport = require('postcss-import'); 

const config = {
    plugins: [
        //Some plugins, like tailwindcss/nesting, need to run before Tailwind,
        postcssImport(),
        tailwindcssNesting(),
        tailwindcss(),
        //But others, like autoprefixer, need to run after,
        autoprefixer
    ]
};

module.exports = config;
```

And my tailwindcss.config.cjs

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config}*/
const config = {
    content: [
        './src/**/*.{html,js,svelte,ts}',
        './node_modules/flowbite-svelte/**/*.{html,js,svelte,ts}'
    ],

    theme: {
        extend: {
            colors: {
                // flowbite-svelte
                primary: {
                    50: '#FFF5F2',
                    100: '#FFF1EE',
                    200: '#FFE4DE',
                    300: '#FFD5CC',
                    400: '#FFBCAD',
                    500: '#FE795D',
                    600: '#EF562F',
                    700: '#EB4F27',
                    800: '#CC4522',
                    900: '#A5371B'
                }
            }
        }
    },

    plugins: [require('flowbite/plugin')],

    darkMode: 'class'
};

module.exports = config;
```

It seems that the function `isNegative` is not preprocessed.
It works well when `isNegative` is not present in the `style` block

The versions used :
vite: 5.0.3
svelte: 4.2.7
flowbite: 2.2.1
tailwindcss: 3.3.6
flowbite-svelte: 0.44.23
postcss: 8.4.32
postcss-load-config: 5.0.2

Comment: Please [edit] your title to describe the problem you're having or question you're asking. Your current title is the useless repetition of the tags, which shouldn't be in the title at all. Your title should be clear and descriptive enough that a future site user skimming a list of search results will know what it contains. You can find tips on writing a good title in [ask].

Comment: "How to use template expressions in a 'style' block?" - In short, you can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have invalid CSS, hence the error:

```css
p {
  …
  color: {isNegative(number) ? 'red' : 'inherit'};
}
```

It seems you are trying to use some kind of JavaScript expression in the CSS but the CSS in the `<style>` tag is not parsed with this in mind.

Instead, consider having two different rules in the `<style>` tag that apply for the different possible states, like:

```html
<main>
  <p class:red={isNegative(number)}>{formatNumber(number)}</p>
</main>

<style>
  main {
    text-align: right;
  }

  p {
    margin: 0; /* Remove default margin to avoid extra space */
    color: inherit;
  }
  
  .red {
    color: red;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Also, if values *have* to be passed, custom CSS properties can be used, e.g. `<p style:--color={isNegative(number) ? 'red' : 'inherit'}>` => `p { color: var(--color); }`. (In this case one might also just use `color` directly, though that affects specificity.)

Comment: Thanks ! I ended up with  choosing the classname with `$: className = isNegative(number) ? 'red' : 'green';` in the "script" block and set the class in the "main" block. This article was also helpful: [link](https://imfeld.dev/writing/svelte_dynamic_css)